# Sci Fi Book about a sick weak wife cloned and gradually replaced by a robot maid

Tags: story-identification

I thought it was by Nicolas Fisk but now can't find it if so.  I remember it had a 1950s American feel to it and that the robot maid is a gift from the husband to the wife who is getting progressively more ill and weak.  I think the robot might be a clone of her but i'm not 100%..
thanks!

Answer (score 8):

'[Compassion Circuit](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=1190)' by John Wyndham. It has a rather creepy ending:

"*The events of this short story are placed not too far ahead in our
own future, where domestic robots are the norm; practically everyone
has a household robot.  Janet, though, didn't like them; however, an
illness forced her to accept the idea of a robot in the house, one
with a new feature. Doctor-recommended, of course.*"
<sub><sup>[technovelgy.com review](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=1190)</sup></sub>

> "**...what I'd really recommend for her is the type they have here. It's
>   something pretty new, this Nurse James model. A specially developed
>   high sensibility job with a quite novel contra-balanced
>   compassion-protection circuit. A very tricky bit of work, that.  Any
>   direct order which a normal robot would obey at once is evaluated by
>   the circuit, weighed against the benefit or harm to the patient, and
>   unless it is beneficial, or at least harmless, it is not obeyed...**"

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much.  *doffs cap

Comment: @user867 - I've found a live link [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjTsOTxu8bLAhWJiRoKHReSDcoQIAgwMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebcache.googleusercontent.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcache%3AarkjJodcm6IJ%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fmrholtslandershomeworkblog.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F10%2Fcompassion-circuit.doc%2B%26cd%3D4%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Dus&usg=AFQjCNGbaIuT_VfEscO3C7UD5T921443ow&sig2=xcNh6eUOhpvdFMnrW0_P9Q). I can't vouch for the copyright but it's 70+ years old, so it's unlikely anyone cares.